# 30% of sugar delivered must be added to get the original quantity of the sugar

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

So, I was solving a maths question from a question booklet in which the language of the question got me instead. Here's how it went:

> A merchant sells the sugar to customer in such a way that 30% of the sugar actually delivered must be added to get the original quantity of sugar asked by the customer. 
> Though the merchant sells the sugar at cost price but he charges additional 10% of what he has invested as transportation cost. 
> Find the net gain percent of the seller.

This is a very simple question indeed if one knew what shopkeeper actually did!
The answer is 40% because initially, SP/CP=130/100, which means 30% profit and in the end merchant also gets 10% profit so, net = 30% + 10% =40%.

I get the transportation part but not the initial part.

From answer now I know that while the customer asked for 130 kgs of sugar the merchant gave only 100, **but how**?

Note: CP means Cost Price and SP means Selling Price.

Comment: The text of the question makes no sense whatever to me - and I'm a retired accountant!

Comment: @WS2 Lol, perhaps it's a merchants' thing (XD)

Comment: The text of the question seems only the start. It is telling us that the merchant short delivers. The customer only received 79% of what they ordered - 100-(70*0.3)%  But what has that got to do with profit? There seems as if there is some information missing.

Comment: @WS2 I have edited the question, please check.

Comment: All this suggests the arrangement to be that the customer is agreeable to paying for 30% more sugar than he receives - and accepts that that is the way that the merchant makes his profit. But oddly the question does not tell you that. I would not consider it a fair question if that is how it appeared in an examination paper.

Comment: @WS2 thank you, partly (or exactly?), I wanted to know that view point too. This is because often times in exams we are simply told like this: The shopkeeper cheated the customer by 10% weight. So, we find the profit to be 11.11%. This again, despite me thinking the question maker has elaborated some scheme, is simply saying in similar way that the shopkeeper cheated the customer by 30% weight BUT a whole lot wordy/mouthful of words.

Comment: @InanimateBeing  This might be a culturally-specific issue, but in the US, if a merchant shorted a customer by 10%, we wouldn't say "the merchant's profit was 11.11%", because that implies that if the merchant was honest, his profit would be zero, and that doesn't make any sense!  We normally use *profit* in a sense like "The merchant's cost for the item is $80 each, and he sells them for $95 each, therefore his profit is $15 per item."

Comment: @stangdon not really. An assumption here (in question) is that the shopkeeper claims to sell their commodity/item at CP but then their shenanigans fall in. Essentially, an honest merchant would then not make profit (this is logical conclusion and nothing senseless about it). Your example is independent of this and fine as is. True that real life not got much to do with it (the OP question) but that's hardly a concern for our education system.

Comment: What does CP mean? I once worked in an industry where it was commercially accepted for the weight delivered to vary by as much as 10% of the weight ordered, but the price charged was based on the weight  actually delivered. The question makes little sense.

Comment: @JeffMorrow I have edited the question. Pardon my faulty assumption of those 2 abbreviations being universal in nature which they clearly aren't. Hope the question makes sense now.

Comment: So the seller delivers 76.923% of the ordered weight, but charges the cost price per unit times the ordered weight. Is that what is meant? Is the ten percent transportation charge levied on the ordered weight or the delivered weight? Very badly worded problem for a very sketchy transaction.

Comment: @InanimateBeing "An assumption here (in question) is that the shopkeeper claims to sell their commodity/item at CP but then their shenanigans fall in"  As an assumption, that would need to be stated.  As it is, I think this is just a really badly worded problem.

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457) "from a question booklet" is **not**/ sufficient.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I always keep in mind to provide proper attribution but the above question is from a booklet of a local institution which contains compilation of questions from different sources and that they haven't mentioned anywhere. So, one cannot find it on internet via title search. Booklet is called 2106 (yes, it's a number).

Comment: @JeffMorrow "Is that what is meant?" That's what I want to know too, but the answer given would say yes. "Is the ten percent transportation charge levied on the ordered weight or the delivered weight?" 10% is levied on the amount that he had invested. So, that would be the cost price of what he's selling.

Comment: @stangdon *This might be a culturally-specific issue, but in the US, if a merchant shorted a customer by 10%, we wouldn't say "the merchant's profit was 11.11%",* What on earth makes you think that that is something unique to the United States? I feel sure that Venetian merchants of the eighth century, who first used the practice of modern bookkeeping, would have taken the same view.